# Php image captcha code generator

Tags: php, captcha, spam

I have a script for my website with is for generating a captcha code to block spam bots but it seems to be bypassed. The site is made in VLd personals which have a captcha code that is very weak. Its easily by passed by bots such that in a day got 3K registrations.

I have modified the original code to the code below but its still bypassed although they greatly reduce the number of spam accounts

```
<?php


session_start();


//------------------------------------------
// Generate captcha
//------------------------------------------
captcha($_SESSION['captcha']);


//------------------------------------------
// Generate captcha
//------------------------------------------
function captcha($magic_number)
{
    $height = 55;
    $width = 280;

    if (extension_loaded('gd'))
    {
        // create the image
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        // background
        $color1 = imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(255, 255), mt_rand(255, 255), mt_rand(255, 255));
        $color2 = imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(255, 255), mt_rand(255, 255), mt_rand(255, 255));

        $direction = array_rand(array('horizontal', 'vertical',));

        if ( mt_rand(0, 100) === 1 )
        {
            $temp = $color1;
            $color1 = $color2;
            $color2 = $temp;
        }

        $color1 = imagecolorsforindex($image, $color1);
        $color2 = imagecolorsforindex($image, $color2);

        $steps = ( $direction === 'horizontal' ) ? $width : $height;

        $r1 = ( $color1['red'] - $color2['red'] ) / $steps;
        $g1 = ( $color1['green'] - $color2['green'] ) / $steps;
        $b1 = ( $color1['blue'] - $color2['blue'] ) / $steps;

        if ( $direction === 'horizontal' )
        {
            $x1 =& $i;
            $y1 = 0;
            $x2 =& $i;
            $y2 = $height;
        }
        else
        {
            $x1 = 0;
            $y1 =& $i;
            $x2 = $width;
            $y2 =& $i;
        }

        for ( $i = 0; $i <= $steps; $i++ )
        {
            $r2 = $color1['red'] - floor($i * $r1);
            $g2 = $color1['green'] - floor($i * $g1);
            $b2 = $color1['blue'] - floor($i * $b1);
            $color = imagecolorallocate($image, $r2, $g2, $b2);

            imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color);
        }

        // add a few random lines
        for ( $i = 0, $count = mt_rand(5, 50); $i < $count; $i++ )
        {
            $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(100, 255), mt_rand(50, 120));
            imageline($image, mt_rand(0, $width), 0, mt_rand(0, $width), $height, $color);
        }

        // calculate character font-size and spacing
        $default_size = min($width, $height * 2) / strlen($magic_number);
        $spacing = (int) ($width * 0.9 / strlen($magic_number));

        // draw each captcha character with varying attributes
        for ( $i = 0, $strlen = strlen($magic_number); $i < $strlen; $i++ )
        {
            $font = "../fonts/expressions-soul.ttf";

            $color = imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0, 150), mt_rand(0, 150), mt_rand(0, 150));
            $angle = mt_rand(-70, $height);

            $size = $default_size / 5 * mt_rand(8, 12);
            $box = imageftbbox($size, $angle, $font, $magic_number[$i]);

            $x = $spacing / 3 + $i * $spacing;
            $y = $height / 2 + ($box[2] - $box[5]) / 4;

            imagefttext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $magic_number[$i]);
        }

        // display image
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Connection: close");
        imagejpeg($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    }
}
// End function


?>
```

Just looking for suggestions for ways to make it hard to be read by computers

Comment: I would suggest not using Captcha but try with a "bot trap" : add an extra field to your form that you hide with CSS so that no human will actually fill it. Usually bots fill all the fields they find, so you could tell that if this field is filled with anything, that was a bot doing the request... would that be a solution for you ? As I see it, it offers the extra-advantage of don't bothering the users... I myself sometimes have a hard time guessing a Captcha.

Comment: Is it possible that you implemented the captcha not safe enough? For the captcha itself, I think the best way is 'click on the cat in the picture' showing shadows of different animals. Reading pixel perfect text from image is too easy for bots.